# How to whois new TLDs?

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu-12.04, whois, tld

How can I look up new TLDs, such as .email, .guru, etc., using the `whois` command in linux?

Running `whois` on a new TLD only gives the response:

```
No whois server is known for this kind of object.
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can manually configure the whois servers for the new TLDs.

Just create the file `/etc/whois.conf` and add the following content and you will be able to look up the new TLDs:

[whois.conf](http://www.unpm.org/wiki/Sample_whois.conf) (Github Mirror: [whois.conf](https://gist.github.com/thde/3890aa48e03a2b551374))

The whois.conf is using [regular expressions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man5/whois.conf.5.html).

Comment: Wow, thanks! Can you tell me what source you get this information from? I imagine this list will become dated over time.

Comment: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db just click on the domain

Comment: I scripted harvesting the WHOIS servers from the latest IANA data and have updated this answer.

Comment: Is that necessary? Because whois is able to resolve the older gTLDs...

Comment: Different versions of whois have different snapshots of whois servers, so different people would need different lists -- especially if they're stuck on an older distro for some reason.  Using the entire list every time makes it work for everyone.  Also, it is much easier to simply harvest all of them. :-)

Comment: I can see your point =).

Comment: @RoyceWilliams Would you be so kind as to post the script you used to harvest?

Comment: I've tried this on Ubuntu and noticed that data returned for .com TLDs return far less data. For example, not even the Registrant name is returned. Deleting the `\.com$ whois.verisign-grs.com` line from the above list restored the superior default behavior. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: @TomBrossman I'm not completely sure why this is and I haven't looked into it any further than to discover that it has something to do with the lookup not going to the registrar level. If you use the gwhois.org tool from one of the below answers, you can see this illustrated much better.

Comment: @TomBrossman Correct. There are different Whois Servers for .com domains. Maybe it's possible to enter all of these in the whois.conf. The easiest way is probably to just remove the .com entry.

Comment: Since it is quite a bit of effort to update this list, it is rather easy to accidentally miss one of the TLDs, which is what happened when I updated this question last weekend. I suggested an edit to add in the missing TLD, but the edit was rejected. Given all that effort, I'm not going to be making further edits to this answer. I will be maintaining an updated list [here](//www.unpm.org/wiki/Sample_whois.conf).

Comment: @Paul I just updated the post. Maybe you can leave a comment if theres an update to this list.

Comment: @thde I have updated [my list](https://www.unpm.org/wiki/Sample_whois.conf).

Comment: I hadn't realized that the raw list isn't included in the answer anymore. I recently had to refresh the list because I needed a jwhois.conf. My update scripts are now published at https://github.com/roycewilliams/iana-whois-conf - so that anyone can refresh their own lists as needed.

Answer (score 15):

You can easily get the right whois server **directly from IANA** without editing additional files or tables.

**Example for ".de" TLD**

Linux, OSX (and compatible):

```
whois -h whois.iana.org .de |
  egrep -e '^whois:' |
  sed -e 's/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*/ /g' |
  cut -d " " -f 2
```

Have fun

Comment: I wish your answer were upvoted much more; this is a perfect and correct generalized solution. No hard-coding should be needed (otherwise every OS would need to hard-code WHOIS servers for every new TLD!). Why this isn't the default behavior for the `whois` utility, I'm not sure (maybe to reduce load?). Anyway, props and thank you.

Comment: Querying a domain would work like this using your idea: `whois -h $(whois -h whois.iana.org .TLD | grep '^whois:' | sed 's/whois:\s*//') example.TLD`. Interestingly though, it's sufficient to use `whois.nic.TLD` as a database host for most (or maybe all?) TLD's, as pointed out by @Andrew.

Comment: This seems not to work for all TLD's. For `.tube` the responsible server is not published. Probably because the IANA server is responsible as `whois -h whois.iana.org nic.tube` works.

Answer (score 12):

Most whois clients hard-code the TLD whos servers, instead of actively retrieving the whois server from IANA when performing for a TLD that is not already known to the client.

I have built my own online whois lookup tool you can use http://gwhois.org/ that supports all TLDs and IP addresses since all lookups start at IANA and then traverse to the registry and registrar as needed.

I have also spent a lot of time building an intelligent whois parser that displays the whois data in a user-friendly manner.

Example screenshots:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Thank you for this, since I don't run Ruby, this answer would work better for me. I run Ubuntu Server 12.04 and it looks like the `gwhois` package requires an additional 25 packages to be installed from official repository. Not that I would miss the ~4.4MB of storage, are all these really necessary for the package to run correctly?

Comment: Oh. Gwhois.org is not related to the 'gwhois' packages on Linux. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Okay, that can work, but no command line tool? I'm hoping to solve the command line issue somehow.

Comment: No command line tool at this time. I didn't catch that part of your question. I've been thinking about making a command line tool, though. I suppose you can follow my blog (listed on GWhois.org) for updates.

Comment: I will do that. It's rather annoying that the managers of `whois` aren't doing this already, given what a universal tool it is.

Comment: Yeah. The main reason why I decided to build my own whois tool was because I was not satisfied with any of the solutions already out there. :)

Comment: Is it possible to make what you have work by editing the `whois.conf` file, as recommended in the answer by @thde? I realize that solution is using a static file, but maybe a script could be used? I like your approach to the solution vs static file, but I tend to do most of my lookups through command line.

Comment: +1 Brilliant, thank you for making this - works perfectly. May not answer the OP as such but exactly what I needed!

Comment: @iglvzx I like your tool. Have you thought of open-sourcing the code so that we can activately make changes to the app?

Comment: sadly https://gwhois.org is offline since April 4, 2023.

Answer (score 12):

This appears to work for most new tlds:

Server hostname is in the form:  whois.nic.newtldname

e.g.:

```
whois -h whois.nic.host example.host
```

"This name is reserved by the Registry in accordance with ICANN Policy." etc etc etc

Also, browsing to `http://nic.newtldname` typically takes you to the Registry / Launch page.

Comment: Fantastic! Why does this work even though the hosts officially listed by IANA are different for most domain registries? Is this documented somewhere, i.o.w. is this officially supported by IANA or ICANN? -- The dynamic version of your solution would be `whois -h $(whois -h whois.iana.org .TLD | grep '^whois:' | sed 's/whois:\s*//') example.TLD`

Comment: Do you know of any other whois servers that accept the TLD extension to query for that TLD? I know of two: `whois.nic.$ext` and `$ext.whois-servers.net` -- I'm looking for others to add to my list.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the standard linux client, the definitions have not been updated yet to include the new TLDS.

You have two possible solutions:

1. Grab the list of all new gTLDs and pass the whois host as parameter to the whois client
2. Use an alternative client. I'm currently doing my best to keep the [Ruby WHOIS client](http://ruby-whois.org) in sync with the new gTLDs, so you can use it. It also offers a CLI.

Comment: I'm not sure where to grab a list of all new gTLDs and I'm not sure how to pass the whois host as parameter to the whois client. I don't have Ruby installed on my server. This isn't a good answer.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/weppos/whois/blob/master/data/tld.json) is Simone's list of whois hosts for tlds, [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whois) is a copy of the whois man page .

Comment: [IANA's Root Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db) includes whois servers, along with other information for TLDs. (It's near the bottom of a TLD's entry.)

Answer (score 2):

On OS X, the whois tool doesn't seem to be built with the /etc/whois.conf support ([Just like slackware?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/'whois'-not-reading-etc-whois-conf-4175523226/)). The easy way to fix this seems to be to instal the "duped" whois from [homebrew](http://brew.sh/). You can do that with

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew update
brew install whois
brew untap homebrew/dupes
```

That way, it will use a updated list of whois servers (But I only tested with .so and .ninja domains).

Comment: Good to know this. A one liner to install updated `whois` CLI is `brew install homebrew/dupes/whois`

Answer (score 2):

For updating your /etc/whois.conf you can use a script like

```
/*
 * Usage : node generateWhoisConf.js > /etc/whois.conf
 */

var json = require('comment-json');
var request = require('request');

request('https://github.com/weppos/whois/raw/master/data/tld.json', function(error, response, body){
  var obj = json.parse(body);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    if(obj[key].host){
      console.log(key.replace(/\./g,'\\.') + '$ ' + obj[key].host);
    }
  });
});
```

https://gist.github.com/HugoPoi/4694a99f5a9d9b2c558557bbdd113f54

This other github repository provide good data about whois server https://github.com/whois-server-list/whois-server-list

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use ***TLD*.whois-servers.net** as the whois server, e.g:

```
whois -h mobi.whois-servers.net npr.mobi
```

The *whois-server.net* domain (run by CenterGate LLC, no affiliation) contains a hopefully up-to-date list of DNS CNAME redirects to official TLD whois servers, e.g:

```
dig mobi.whois-servers.net
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mobi.whois-servers.net. 146     IN      CNAME   whois.dotmobiregistry.net.
```

Comment: In most cases this works. There's even a shorter syntax (at least in OSX): `whois -c mobi npr.mobi`. Sadly it doesn't work for all domains at the time of writing e.g. `whois -c tube nic.tube`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was not very sophisticated.  I could not look up a certain TLD under Debian Wheezy or Squeeze, or in OS X El Capitan or Snow Leopard.  I found out that I could look up the TLD in Debian Jessie though.  On the Debian machines I just grabbed the source for whois for Jessie and built it; works fine now.  For OS X, I grabbed a newer version of whois through MacPorts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problematic server response to one of my requests.

In this case, using the `-a` switch was simple and worked great:

```
whois -a [your_request_here]
```

From `man`:

```
[This flag is] understood by whois.ripe.net and some other RIPE-like servers:
-a
    Also search all the mirrored databases.
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can just use a better tool. E.g. GNU **jwhois** which is flexibly search for appropriate `whois` server first, then do the actual lookup using that server.

> jwhois an improved Whois client capable of selecting Whois server to
>   query based on a flexible configuration file using either regular
>   expressions or CIDR blocks

GNU path : https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/jwhois/
Github one:  https://github.com/jonasob/jwhois

Comment: Doesn't work for new TLDs.

Comment: Ironically, this was the reason why I couldn't whois the new TLDs. For some reason, this tool was the one installed by default. I installed one of the plain whois and I was able to query the new TLDs, no hack needed.